# Switch statement not displaying correct answer

Tags: java, switch-statement

For some reason,

```
int x = 5;
switch (x) {
    case 3 : x += 1;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 4 : x += 2;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 5 : x += 3;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 6 : x++;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 7 : x += 2;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 8 : x--;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 9 : x++;
    System.out.println(x);
}
```

(Disregard the SOP's), the result of this switch statement keeps giving me 11, when calculated on paper I keep getting 10. I think it has something to do with the increments, but can't figure out why it's displaying 11. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i think it's pretty straight forward:

```
int x = 5;
    switch (x) {
    case 3 : x += 1;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 4 : x += 2;
    System.out.println(x);
    case 5 : x += 3;     /* found a match, so start here.  now x=8  */
    System.out.println(x);
    case 6 : x++;  /* no break statement, so now x=9  */
    System.out.println(x);
    case 7 : x += 2;  /* no break statement, so now x=11  */
    System.out.println(x);
    case 8 : x--;  /* no break statement, so now x=10  */
    System.out.println(x);
    case 9 : x++;  /* no break statement, so now x=11  */
    System.out.println(x);

    }
```

Comment: So a switch statement automatically does the next case in its body if there is no break after the first case? I thought after x=8 in case 5, the case would go to 8, then 7, then 9

Comment: @PatrickBui: Yes to your first sentence, no to your second.  It finds the first match, and executes every line after (in order) until it hits a break statement.

Comment: @PatrickBui No switch does not work like that.  Just think it works like: first it hit the `switch()` statement, and base on the value at that moment, jump to the corresponding label, and execute all statements starting from that label

Comment: @Gerrat But since there is no break after case 9, why does the switch not go back to case 1 and do an infinite loop? Is it because the switch statement stops at the last case whether there's a break; or not? (Java beginner here!)

Comment: @PatrickBui:  The switch statement isn't a loop.  It goes though once.  It goes through from top to bottom.  It finds the first match, then executes everything after until it hits a `break` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no `break` instruction in your switch, cases `5-9` are executed. `X` calculation:

```
x = 5 + 3 + 1 + 2 -1 + 1 == 11
```